# Two div tags on the right side overriding each other

Tags: html, css, jsp

There are two div tag. First one is display 20px from right side and another is displaying 103px from right and both are in the same row.

some times both were getting overridden because of the text inside the div tags. the text will vary based on some option. its dynamic. sometimes it wont get overridden because the text size is low.

i want the following scenarios to be done.

first div tag's right would be 20 px. second div tag right's needs to be starts from the left edge of the first div tag. is this possible? can anyone help me?

```
        .second-button {
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #00aeef ;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 22px;
                right: 103px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

        .first-button {
                position: absolute;
                right: 20px;
                bottom: 16px;
            }
```

The above style i am currently following. Based on that can any one give the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.main-div {
    text-align: right;  
}
.div1 {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #CCC;
}
.div1:last-child {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

<div class="main-div">
  <div class="div1">This is first div</div>
  <div class="div1">This is second div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

to both of your div's add the word-wrap: break-word; css give them the desired width and you should be great

Comment: Thanks a lot for your concern. but whether we have any way to do without breaking the word like what i mentioned in the question?

Comment: If you don't break the word then you cannot be sure that all the text is shown inside the div so if you want a structured page you will have to do that!

Answer (score 0):

I made some code.. might be it will help you

```html
<div class="abc">First Div</div>
  <div class="abc">Second Div</div>

<style> .abc{float:right; margin-right:20px;}

</style>
```

Comment: its working but when integrating its not working. i will try again

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<style type="text/css">
    #div1{
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    #div1, #div2{
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

<div id="div1">
</div>
<div id="div2">
</div>
```

Comment: are the buttons inside divs?